# Link errors while using CString::AllocSysString in VC++ 6.0

Tags: c++, mfc

Added the following code

```
BSTR pbstrBuffer;
pbstrBuffer = buff.AllocSysString();
```

I got the following error when building the project:

```
Linking...
  Creating library pcciortl.lib and object pcciortl.exp .obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned short  * __thiscall CString::AllocSysString(void)const " (?AllocSysString@CString@@QBEPAGXZ)
```

c:\pct3/pcciortl.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.

Other CString methods seems to be ok. What should I do?

Comment: That code on its own is not safe at all. You dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: CString::AllocSysString() is an MFC library function.  You *must* include MFC in your build.  You *should* include the version that's compatible with your compiler (e.g. MFC100.dll for MSVS 2010): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library

Comment: @chris, you are right. I omitted the part of allocation memory for BSTR.

Comment: @paulsm4 Issue was that the basic MFC libraries dont contain this function. You need the mfco42d.lib which is specifically for OLE support.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to manually include the `mfco42d.lib` and then figured out the real solution to include one of the MFC include files in the project

```
#include <afxole.h>         // MFC OLE classes
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC OLE automation classes
```

What it does is to include the library `mfco42d.lib` in Visual C++ 6.0

Comment: This is called auto-linking - Auto-linking is a mechanism for automatically determining which libraries to link to while building a C or C++ program. It is activated by means of #pragma comment(lib, <name>) statements in the header files of the library.
Most Windows compilers support auto-linking, while GCC does not support auto-linking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-linking)